# How to set environment variables in AWS-codebuild for Windows 2019 at build time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

It seems that in AWS-codebuild variables are not propagated between commands for the windows 2019 environment.

With this `buildspec.yml`

```yaml
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    MY_VAR_0: $(git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h)

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - $Env:MY_VAR_1 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
      - Get-ChildItem Env:MY_VAR_*
      # build commands here

artifacts:
  name: $MY_VAR_0
```

I get in the logs:

```
[Container] 2020/12/14 11:41:27 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2020/12/14 11:41:27 Running command $Env:MY_VAR_1 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h

[Container] 2020/12/14 11:41:27 Running command Get-ChildItem Env:MY_VAR_*

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
MY_VAR_0                       $(git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%...

[Container] 2020/12/14 11:41:28 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
```

The problem here are

- `MY_VAR_0` is set to the string `$(git log ...` and not the output of the command.
- `MY_VAR_1` is not propagated to following commands in `phases.build.commands`
- and of course my artifacts end in the wrong place.

---

Up to now the only way I found to solve this problem is

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        $Env:MY_VAR_0 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
        $Env:MY_VAR_1 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
        Get-ChildItem Env:MY_VAR_*
        # first build command here
      - |
        $Env:MY_VAR_0 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
        $Env:MY_VAR_1 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
        Get-ChildItem Env:MY_VAR_*
        # second build command here

artifacts:
  name: $(git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h)
```

with the following log:

```
[Container] 2020/12/14 12:25:18 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2020/12/14 12:25:18 Running command $Env:MY_VAR_0 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
$Env:MY_VAR_1 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
Get-ChildItem Env:MY_VAR_*
# first build command here


Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
MY_VAR_1                       2020-12-14_eccfb77                              
MY_VAR_0                       2020-12-14_eccfb77                              

[Container] 2020/12/14 12:25:19 Running command $Env:MY_VAR_0 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
$Env:MY_VAR_1 = & git log -n 1 --date=short --pretty=format:%cd_%h
Get-ChildItem Env:MY_VAR_*
# second build command here


Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
MY_VAR_1                       2020-12-14_eccfb77                              
MY_VAR_0                       2020-12-14_eccfb77                              

[Container] 2020/12/14 12:25:20 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
```

What I do not like in this approach is that I have to repeat the code for computing the MY_VAR_* values at the begin of each build command. (And no, I do not consider feasible to have a single, multiline huge build command.) Moreover the same code has to be repeated in `artifacts.name`

### questions

1. How do I propagate environment variables computed at build-time between different `phases.*.commands`?
2. Why is `$(...)` expanded in `artifacts.name` but not in `env.variables.MY_VAR_0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to #1:

it looks like setting Environment variables in `Env:` drive silently fails. However, using local variable syntax `$Foo = "bar"` seems to work between commands as well as phases.

For example, in the following:

```yaml
version: 0.2
env:
  shell: powershell.exe
phases:
  pre_build: 
    commands:
      - $foo = "bar"
      - echo $foo
  build:
    commands:
      - echo $foo
```

both `echo` commands print `bar`.

Answer to #2:

`artifacts.name` always uses the `shell` language (unix), where when setting a variable you are in either `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` depending on what you have `env.shell` set to in the buildspec. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.name)